# JSONArray alternative in Android

Tags: android, json

I'm attempting to parse a string that contains an array of JSON objects, but the org.json.JSONArray is not supported until the API 19 (Kit-Kat) operating system. For obvious reasons I need to figure out a way around this. Is there a better alternative to this? Or am I using this method incorrectly?

Here is the code that keeps telling me I need API 19 or higher:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            info = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = info.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String article = c.getString(TAG_ARTICLE);
                String timestamp = c.getString(TAG_TIMESTAMP);
                String datestring = c.getString(TAG_DATESTRING);

                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                map.put(TAG_ARTICLE, article);
                map.put(TAG_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
                map.put(TAG_DATESTRING, datestring);

                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { TAG_TITLE,TAG_ARTICLE, TAG_TIMESTAMP,TAG_DATESTRING }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title,R.id.article, R.id.timestamp,R.id.date_string});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

btw I am using an AsyncTask to put the information into a ListView. I have another class to fetch the result of the webpage. Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that org.json.JSONArray is only supported in API 19?

Comment: What @SteveBenett basically is saying: [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) has been around since API level 1.

Comment: Eclipse is telling me that JSONArray is only supported in API 19 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new API 19 function you are using is:

```
info = new JSONArray(result);
```

Since result is already an JSONArray, why do you need to create another?

Comment: WOWOWOWOWOWOWOWOWOW!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You are right, I had no reason to create a JSONArray from (what already was) a JSONArray! I'm such a noob :) btw it works now

Answer (score 0):

Dude try this framework is much better

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

or

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution under 19API lvl:

First of all. Make a Gson obj. --> `Gson gson = new Gson();`

Second step is get your jsonObj as String with StringRequest(instead of JsonObjectRequest)

The last step to get JsonArray...

```
YoursObjArray[] yoursObjArray = gson.fromJson(response, YoursObjArray[].class);
```